# Weird graphics issue only on Desktop and other ubuntu apps

Tags: graphics, intel

I was having an issue after a game caused a GPU hang that forced me to have to do a hard reset and I was having a scrambled display issue, but I fixed that by switching to sna acceleration. But now every few seconds a message comes up saying "System Program Problem"

Here is what the window says.

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error

ExecutablePath

 /usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py

Package

xserver-xorg-video-intel2:2.21.15~precise~ppa1.1 [origin:LP-PPA-glasen-intel-driver]

ProblemType

Crash

Title

GPU lockup IPEHR:0x79000002 IPEHR:0x0b140001

ApportVersion

2.0.2-0ubuntu17.6

Architecture

amd64
```

Comment: Do you need help with fixing the graphical issue you had, or do you need help with getting apport to stop spamming you with error reports?

Comment: Well since I switched to sna acceleration the weird graphics thing stopped.

I read that apport likes to do what it is doing.

Also another problem. My laptop trackpad is not functioning. I can only use the mouse connectected to my USB.

Comment: If the graphics are working fine and you just want apport to stop bugging you, you can safely remove it. `sudo apt-get remove apport` in the terminal should work just fine. It's not going to hurt you at all; many people remove apport on the other community spins like L/X/Kubuntu because it just doesn't stop.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, also would you know why my trackpad would stop working? It was working perfectly fine before all this happened.

Comment: It would be appropriate to make another question for your trackpad. I would check to see if you have a button that turns it off and on, and try that first.

Comment: Those are bugs. You should report them to launchpad