# Dell Inspiron 15(3521) Trackpad refuses to work

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I am having another weird issue that happened after this issue V

[Weird graphics issue only on Desktop and other ubuntu apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420391/weird-graphics-issue-only-on-desktop-and-other-ubuntu-apps?noredirect=1#comment542671_420391)

My Laptop trackpad is refusing to work at all. I am only able to use my mouse with a usb connected mouse.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:649a Microdia
```

Comment: Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Comment: I've edited my question post with the output of lsusb